# Continuous delivery css issue with Visual Studio Online to Azure website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops, continuous-delivery

I am using Git to push my project to Visual Studio Online. my project is linked to an azure website for continuous integration and delivery.

I have made changes to the Site.css file and pushed the changes to Visual Studio Online.  the automatic build deployed the project to my azure website.

but my changes to the Site.css were not deployed to the website. although my other changes to the views and controllers are OK.

I have reviewed and verified that the updated Site.css is pushed successfully to Visual Studio Online. but for some reason it is not included or applied in the deployment.

when I publish the project from my local VS.2013 to the azure website it works fine and the css is updated.

the problem is in the continuous delivery from Visual Studio Online to Azure website.

what is required to include the Site.css in the continuous delivery ?

Comment: How are you verifying that "changes to the Site.css were not deployed to the website"?   Some things to try - refresh your browser. Restart your website. Check the Build Action for Site.css in Visual Studio - it should be "Content".

Comment: Also, you can login to the scm site for your azure web app - it's https://<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net (need to be already authenticated to azure) - go into DebugConsole, browse to site/wwwroot and then to your css file - does the modified date reflect your changes? how about the file content?  if it looks good, and your site is still not reflecting it, likely the browser caching it on you

Comment: Do you remember how you resolved this one?